# How to edit an Android app?

Tags: android, apk

I need to edit an Android app just to change some text that was written incorrectly. I have the `.apk` files, so how would I modify them?

Comment: You can't. Consider the .apk the same as an executable on Windows; you need the source to make changes. If you could just edit the .apk at will to change the app, you could change every app to be your property or contain your name.

Comment: Why would I need to make every app to be my property or contain my name? I just need to change some text in the app that is my property already. I would ask the developer that created it for me but, unfortunately, they're out of reach now. What source do I need to change the text in the app?

Comment: The project source folder and all of the files it contains. When you make these changes you'll have to re-compile and build the app. If you just have apk you can't make any changes to it.

Comment: @Iliya: Piracy comes to mind - if you could readily change any application to appear to be written by you (copyright messages, window captions, etc.), it would make it much harder to prevent theft of someone else's app. If the app is yours (meaning you wrote it), you should have the source (meaning the Java code that makes up the app that was put into the .apk), and you can change it easily. If the app was written by someone else and you purchased it, it's not your 'property' (unless you bought the source/rights as well), and you should contact the author for change requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to decompile the apk as Davis suggested, can use tools such as [apkTool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) , then if you need to change the source code you would need other tools to do that.

You would then need to put the apk back together and sign it, if you don't have the original key used to sign the apk this means the new apk will have a different signature.

If the developer employed any obfuscation or other techniques to protect the app then it gets more complicated.

In short its a pretty complex and technical procedure, so if the developer is really just out of reach, its better to wait until he is in reach. And ask for the source code next time.

Answer (score 10):

Generally speaking, a software product isn't your "property already", as you said in the comment. Most of the times (I won't be irresponsible to say anything in open), it's *licensed* to you. A license to use some thing is not the same thing as owning (property rights) that very same thing.

That's because there are authorship, copyright, intellectual property rights applicable to it. I don't know how things work in United States (or in your country), but it's generally accepted that the work of a mind, a creative work, must not be changed in its nature as such to make the expression of art to be different than that expression that the author intended. That applies for example, in some cases, to architectural work (in most countries, you can't change the appearance of a building to "desfigure" the work of art of the architect, without his prior consent). Exceptions are made, obviously, when the author expressly authorizes such changes (e.g., Creative Commons licenses, open source licenses etc.).

Anyway, that's why you see in most EULAs the typical sentence: "*this software is licensed, not sold*". That's the purpose and reason why.

Now that you understand the reasons why you can't wander around changing other people's art, **let me be technical**.

There are possible ways to decompile Java programs. You can use `dex2jar`, it provides a somewhat good start for you to start looking for things and changes. And perhaps rebuild the code by mounting back the pieces together. Good luck, as most people obfuscate their codes to make that harder.

However, let me say that it's still forbidden to change programs, as I said above. And it's extremely unethical. It makes me sad that people do that with no scruples (not saying it's your case, just warning you). It shouldn't need people to be at the other side to understand that. Or maybe that's just me, who lives in a country where piracy is rampant.

The tools are always out there. But the conscience, unfortunately, not always.

**edit: in case it isn't clear enough already, I do NOT approve the use of these programs. I use them myself to check how hard my own applications are to be reverse engineered. But I also think that explaning is always better than denial (better be here).**

Comment: Ah, and after using dex2jar, you should use some program to reverse engineer the jar files. One of the programs that come to my mind is "jd-gui".

Answer (score -1):

First you have to download file x-plore and installed it..
After that open it and find the thoes you want to edit..
After that just rename the file 
Xyz.apk to xyz.zip
After that open that file and you can see some folders.. then just go and edit the app..

Comment: Altough it is possible this way; @Ken White clearly states why it shouldn't be done. This should not be encouraged on SO.

Comment: it's not about encouraging such things on SO, kindly see this in a learning point of view.